# Smack: ReconnectionManager sends duplicate login requests while reconnecting

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I'm creating an android Xmpp client using Smack(4.1.7). While implementing the automatic re-connection feature using ReconnectionManager, I find that the library sends duplicate login requests. Because of that the second Reconnection is rejected by server with error - `Client is already logged in`.

Here is the XML dump from Smack:

```
6-20 15:42:37.704 26369-26612/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: XMPPConnection closed due to an exception (0)
06-20 15:42:37.714 26369-26612/in.gappi.gappichat W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
06-20 15:42:37.714 26369-26612/in.gappi.gappichat W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:592)
06-20 15:42:37.714 26369-26612/in.gappi.gappichat W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:556)
.....
.....
06-20 15:42:38.714 26369-26829/in.gappi.gappichat D/GappiXmpp: Reconnecting 10
06-20 15:42:38.714 26369-26829/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 10
.....
06-20 15:42:48.724 26369-26829/in.gappi.gappichat D/GappiXmpp: Reconnecting 0
06-20 15:42:48.724 26369-26829/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: XMPPConnection (0) will reconnect in 0
06-20 15:42:48.894 26369-27615/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='gappi.in' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='9739937980@gappi.in' xml:lang='en'>
06-20 15:42:48.984 26369-27616/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='11040239326876846172' from='gappi.in' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
06-20 15:42:48.984 26369-27616/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: RECV (0): <stream:features><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='PXc8x7mNN6cEIZgjsEishHW4d3E='/><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/><starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>
06-20 15:42:48.994 26369-27615/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: SENT (0): <auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-1'>biwsbj05NzM5OTM3OTgwLHI9QncuaHNmXV8lOGAyInQzTEJacnpkXmBPVCR3Rl90J0M=</auth>
06-20 15:42:49.094 26369-27616/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: RECV (0): <challenge xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>cj1Cdy5oc2ZdXyU4YDIidDNMQlpyemReYE9UJHdGX3QnQ0RsUkhLTTRJU2V5ZG1LNGtSRThva3c9PSxzPUpJemJtbXAxaExzRFNZV042M1EyK0E9PSxpPTQwOTY=</challenge>
06-20 15:42:49.264 26369-26388/in.gappi.gappichat I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 90062(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 20(540KB) LOS objects, 32% free, 33MB/49MB, paused 1.826ms total 137.089ms
06-20 15:42:49.564 26369-27615/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: SENT (0): <response xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>Yz1iaXdzLHI9QncuaHNmXV8lOGAyInQzTEJacnpkXmBPVCR3Rl90J0NEbFJIS000SVNleWRtSzRrUkU4b2t3PT0scD16UXpxR2xVeDArTnF1M1lERkxhN2lubXphNnc9</response>
06-20 15:42:49.654 26369-27616/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: RECV (0): <success xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>dj1vdHAxTGtUVVZMZW1GdEVLOXdmZWlqQTdWK1E9</success>
06-20 15:42:49.654 26369-27615/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='gappi.in' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='9739937980@gappi.in' id='11040239326876846172' xml:lang='en'>
06-20 15:42:49.654 26369-27615/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: SENT (0): <resume xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='2' previd='g2gCbQAAAAVTbWFja2gDYgAABbpiAAbIgmIAAAIt'/>
06-20 15:42:49.734 26369-27616/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='5567512457513756075' from='gappi.in' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
06-20 15:42:49.734 26369-27616/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: RECV (0): <stream:features><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='PXc8x7mNN6cEIZgjsEishHW4d3E='/><bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'/><session xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session'><optional/></session><sm xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:2'/><sm xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><csi xmlns='urn:xmpp:csi:0'/></stream:features>
06-20 15:42:49.814 26369-27616/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: RECV (0): <resumed xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='2' previd='g2gCbQAAAAVTbWFja2gDYgAABbpiAAbIgmIAAAIt'/>
06-20 15:42:49.814 26369-26829/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: User logged (0): 9739937980@gappi.in:5222/Smack
06-20 15:42:49.814 26369-27616/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: RECV (0): <r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>
06-20 15:42:49.814 26369-26829/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: XMPPConnection authenticated (0) and resumed
06-20 15:42:49.814 26369-27615/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: SENT (0): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='2'/>
06-20 15:42:49.824 26369-26829/in.gappi.gappichat D/SMACK: XMPPConnection connected (0)
06-20 15:42:49.834 26369-26829/in.gappi.gappichat D/GappiXmpp: ReconnectionFailed!
06-20 15:42:49.834 26369-26829/in.gappi.gappichat W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$AlreadyLoggedInException: Client is already logged in
06-20 15:42:49.834 26369-26829/in.gappi.gappichat W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.throwAlreadyLoggedInExceptionIfAppropriate(XMPPTCPConnection.java:358)
06-20 15:42:49.834 26369-26829/in.gappi.gappichat W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:452)
06-20 15:42:49.834 26369-26829/in.gappi.gappichat W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:414)
06-20 15:42:49.834 26369-26829/in.gappi.gappichat W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:863)
06-20 15:42:49.834 26369-26829/in.gappi.gappichat W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:364)
06-20 15:42:49.834 26369-26829/in.gappi.gappichat W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.ReconnectionManager$2.run(ReconnectionManager.java:241)
06-20 15:42:49.834 26369-26829/in.gappi.gappichat W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

At times `06-20 15:42:48.894` and `06-20 15:42:49.654` two different `<stream/>` stanzas are sent, which ultimately cause the exception later on.

Is there any reason for such behavior? My client side xmpp code looks like this:

```
  XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration connConfig = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder().setHost(serverAddress)
            .setPort(5222).setDebuggerEnabled(true).setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
            .setUsernameAndPassword(loginUser, passwordUser).setServiceName(serverAddress).build();
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptionDefault(true);
    connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);
    connection.setUseStreamManagement(true);
    connection.setUseStreamManagementResumption(true);

    XMPPConnectionListener connectionListener = new XMPPConnectionListener();
    connection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);
    connection.setPacketReplyTimeout(10000);
    connection.addStanzaAcknowledgedListener(new StanzaListener() {
        @Override
        public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException {
            String id = packet.getStanzaId();
            if (StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(id)) {
                return;
            }
            stanzaAcknowledged(id);
        }
    });

    ReconnectionManager reconnectionManager = ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
    reconnectionManager.setEnabledPerDefault(true);
    reconnectionManager.enableAutomaticReconnection();
```

Comment: any update on this topic? i am facing a similar issue. when i try to reconnect the connection happens and suddenly it gives Stream error conflict saying that client is already logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At times 06-20 15:42:48.894 and 06-20 15:42:49.654 two
>   different  stanzas are sent, which ultimately cause the
>   exception later on.

No, that is not what is causing the exception nor what the exception is about. You see two  *open* tags, which is perfectly normal (See RFC 6120). The exception just tells you that ReconnectionManager couldn't do its job because the connection already is authenticated.

Comment: Even though the exception is raised, the client is connected to server and can send/receive the messages. 
The problem is that the "already logged in" exception fires the "reconnectionFailed" callback.
Is this a Smack library problem then?